# In react-vite, Have someone already seen and fixed the css issue of not being rendered in the browser?

Tags: vite

I had created a simplel TextLink component using the navLink and there present the css based on the condition and the active state. The version of`React-router-dom` that I am using is `6.16.0`. When I click on the navBar link, the active css state is not fully visible in it. By saying this, I mean to say that the css is partially visible.